# Condition does not work

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    aaa
</div>

<div id="b">
    <button>hide aaa</button>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>
```

JS:

```
if($('#a:visible').length > 0) {
    $('a').click(function() {
        alert('a');
    });
}

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#a').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgj4uw6f/

If I click "hide aaa" and then I click on the link, alert is shown. I don't want to show the alert when #a is hidden. How can I change my code?

Answer (score 2):

It's inside-out. You have to check visibility *when the click happens*.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($('#a:visible').length > 0) {
    alert('a');
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#a').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  aaa
</div>

<div id="b">
  <button>hide aaa</button>
</div>

<a href="#">link</a>
JS:
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working changing your condition to inside the click event, like so:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if($('#a:visible').length > 0) {
        alert('a');
    }
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#a').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgj4uw6f/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it! You can check the visibility of an element using `$(element).is(":visible")`.

```
$('a').click(function() {
     if($('#a').is(":visible")) {
        alert('a');
     }
 });


$('button').click(function () {
    $('#a').hide();
});
```